# Updating latest FontAwesome icons with Rails Less Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome, twitter-bootstrap-rails

FontAwesome released a bunch of awesome [new icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and I'm having trouble getting them with my current configuration.

I have a rails application using the "twitter-bootstrap-rails" gem which comes with Fontawesome automatically but it has the old version of FontAwesome that doesn't include the latest icons. I tried what [they suggested here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) but didn't work and ended up messing up everything.

What's the best way to pull the latest FontAwesome icons?

This is how I call FontAwesome in my bootstrap_and_overides.css.less file:

```
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.eot#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-path("fontawesome-webfont.svg");
@import "fontawesome";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The twitter-bootstrap-rails gem uses 3.0.2 fontawesome.

There is a proposal to update to 3.1.1 on github https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/571

Might be worth waiting a little while unless it's super urgent..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue because I did not want to update the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. So I removed/commented out the import of font-awesome from the bootstrap_and_overrides file, then I installed the font-awesome-rails gem and it brought in the latest version just fine.
I think this is better anyway so I can control the updates to font-awesome without it being dependent on the bootstrap gem.